# Can I make the launcher not extend the entire height of my screen?

Tags: 11.10, unity, launcher

I was wondering if it is possible to NOT extend the launcher of unity, like the dock of Gnome Shell?

Answer (score 2):

It is not currently possible to change the length of the launcher, it just has that complete vertical span for now. One of the things being focused on for the next version of Ubuntu is increasing the ability to customize, so hopefully we will see that added as an option soon.

(Just as an aside, installing Gnome-shell is easy in ubuntu 11.10, just type:

```
sudo apt-get install gnome-shell
```

log out and log back in after selecting GNOME from the login screen (click the cog icon by your name))